# Почему не работает useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

Ку, хочу изменить состояние при изменение текущей ссылки для этого у меня есть функции

```
 const onClickItem = (item) => {
    // setCelectTask(item);
    history.push('/lists/'+String(item.id));
    
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const listId = history.location.pathname.split("lists/")[1];
    if (DBList) {
      const selectList= DBList.find((list) => list.id === Number(listId));
      setCelectTask(selectList);
    }
  }, [history.location.pathname]);
```

функция `onClickItem` работает при нажатии на элемент и с ней в все хорошо, но вот `useEffect` отрабатывать совсем не хочет.
Для работы с url я использую `useHistory`
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить массив зависимостей.С `[history.location.pathname]` на `[history, history.location,  history.location.pathname]`

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов, Все равно не хочет работать.

Comment: Напишите внутри просто `console.log("test")`  попробуйте удалить весь массив зависимостей и проверить.Думаю проблема в том что у вас просто объект history не меняется.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов, Внутри `useEffect` у меня брэйк поинт а  внутри  `onClickItem` я вставил `console.log(history.location.pathname) ` и в консоли я вижу разные значения у `history.location.pathname`

Comment: Да и сама url тоже меняется

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов что такое history? Откуда вы её взяли?

Comment: @RTW `history` берется из `useHistory`.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов откуда берётся useHistory?

Comment: @RTW Думаешь у него нету `react-router-dom`?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов думаю что нужно указывать чем и как он пользуется :)

Comment: @RTW указывать или спросить ? 

Comment: @RTW без предоставленной песочницы вообще сложно на вопросы овтетить.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов описание проблемы должно быть воспроизводимо. Если вопрошающий использует стороннюю библиотеку, то нужно это указать в примере.

Comment: @RTW   Согласен.[1 символ]